# Auto filter & copy data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file with data:
[image: Datasheet]

So I want to sort this data as per this image:
[image: sorting image]

Then after that I want to filter data as per sorting order, then copy data in other sheet or other excel file (with header & with active calculation), in ascending order one after below.
Then after hide all slot data except last two row of before calculation, which will look like:
[image: Print View]

Then after that I need the "grand total" of all slot, then set a all column print in one page.

In short I want to do as mentioned step by step below:

1. Assign sort number on criteria column value wise in data sheet
2. Sort
3. Auto-Filter in ascending order & copy-paste with (Header & Active Calculation) One after below.
4. Hide data except last 2 row before calculation (Hide if data is more then 2 row)
5. Grand total
6. Print setup (ALL Column in one page)

Comment: Can you clarify a few things please because I don't quite understand what you're looking for? For step 1, you want to get all the unique items in the Criteria column, is that right? Is the sort order shown in picture 2 assigned manually? Because if it's not then I don't understand what information you're using to sort them.

Comment: Dear Nanhydrin

Q)you want to get all the unique items in the Criteria column, is that right?